# localhost appachectl on mac not resolving

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, httpd.conf

I'm currently running Mohave and I'm trying to run apache using brew.  Here is what I have done.
To ensure `brew` is up to date I'm ran `brew update` two times.
After the update I run `'brew doctor'`
I then have installed and reinstalled httpd.

```
brew install httpd
brew reinstall -s httpd24
```

I then start brew services with and without sudo

```
sudo brew services restart httpd
```

in my httpd.conf which I've confirmed is the one being used by brew.  I have these options:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Listen 80
ServerName localhost
```

When I hit `localhost, localhost:80, localhost:8080, localhost: 8000` and just for kicks `localhost:8443`  I get the error that the server can't be reached.  Meaning localhost is not resolving.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I've read all possible solutions I could find and nothing has worked.

Update: I ran `ps -aef | grep httpd`
This is my result:

```
501 63857 89456   0 10:31AM ttys002    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

Comment: Is apache configured to listed for IPv6 connections, or just IPv4? Some browsers will try IPv6 first, and if that gets rejected they don't retry with IPv4. Try connecting to `127.0.0.1` (the IPv4 address for localhost) and see if that works. BTW, if that's the problem I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find a good match for it.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 & just to test 127.0.0.1:80 not resolving either.  Any ideas of what else I can try?  @GordonDavisson

Comment: That `ps` result indicates the server isn't running (`grep` only finds itself). It might be that the service isn't actually trying to run (I'm not familiar enough with how brew handles this to tell you how to check), or that it's starting and erroring out (check `apachectl configtest` and log files).